# Moving average if the difference between two date-hours is less than value

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

I have a dataset in Excel consisting of 800,000 rows with data, there is registered a value every 4 minutes. I would like to do a moving/running average where I look across 3 hours (so 15 rows of data). However due to outages and other unforeseen events, the data will quite often have a lot times where the is a much larger time between registrations, perhaps hours or days.

I'm trying do the 3 hours moving average but only if the difference between the last items in the running average has a time difference less than 3 hours. If the time difference is above 3 hours, it needs to start a new running average from that value. Is this possible using Excelformulas?

I've added a sample data below, covering column A and B.

| Date/time | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 06-09-2017 18:25 | 1,473 |
| 06-09-2017 18:29 | 1,488 |
| 06-09-2017 18:32 | 1,537 |
| 06-09-2017 18:36 | 1,66 |
| 06-09-2017 18:41 | 1,863 |
| 06-09-2017 18:45 | 2,124 |
| 06-09-2017 18:48 | 2,364 |
| 06-09-2017 18:53 | 2,57 |
| 06-09-2017 18:57 | 2,723 |
| 06-09-2017 19:00 | 2,853 |
| 06-09-2017 19:04 | 2,959 |
| 06-09-2017 19:09 | 3,082 |
| 06-09-2017 19:13 | 3,246 |
| 06-09-2017 19:16 | 3,47 |
| 06-09-2017 19:20 | 3,699 |
| 06-09-2017 19:25 | 3,883 |
| 06-09-2017 19:29 | 4,001 |
| 06-09-2017 19:32 | 4,025 |
| 06-09-2017 19:36 | 3,942 |
| 06-09-2017 19:41 | 3,772 |
| 06-09-2017 19:45 | 3,564 |
| 06-09-2017 19:48 | 3,323 |
| 06-09-2017 19:53 | 3,075 |
| 06-09-2017 19:57 | 2,842 |
| 06-09-2017 20:00 | 2,64 |
| 06-09-2017 20:04 | 2,475 |
| 06-09-2017 20:09 | 2,347 |
| 06-09-2017 20:13 | 2,257 |
| 06-09-2017 20:16 | 2,209 |
| 07-09-2017 20:20 | 2,21 |
| 07-09-2017 20:25 | 2,23 |
| 07-09-2017 20:29 | 2,225 |
| 07-09-2017 20:32 | 2,169 |
| 07-09-2017 20:36 | 2,069 |
| 07-09-2017 20:41 | 1,938 |
| 07-09-2017 20:45 | 1,797 |
| 07-09-2017 20:48 | 1,657 |
| 07-09-2017 20:53 | 1,521 |
| 07-09-2017 20:57 | 1,401 |
| 07-09-2017 21:00 | 1,289 |
| 07-09-2017 21:04 | 1,187 |
| 07-09-2017 21:09 | 1,097 |
| 07-09-2017 21:13 | 1,017 |
| 07-09-2017 21:16 | 0,948 |
| 07-09-2017 21:20 | 0,889 |
| 07-09-2017 21:25 | 0,839 |
| 07-09-2017 21:29 | 0,795 |
| 07-09-2017 21:32 | 0,757 |
| 07-09-2017 21:36 | 0,721 |
| 07-09-2017 21:41 | 0,688 |
| 07-09-2017 21:45 | 0,656 |
| 07-09-2017 21:48 | 0,625 |
| 07-09-2017 21:53 | 0,595 |
| 07-09-2017 21:57 | 0,566 |
| 07-09-2017 22:00 | 0,539 |
| 07-09-2017 22:04 | 0,511 |
| 07-09-2017 22:09 | 0,487 |
| 07-09-2017 22:13 | 0,475 |
| 07-09-2017 22:16 | 0,468 |
| 07-09-2017 22:20 | 0,461 |

Comment: Is the dates true dates or text dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've gotten this to work with the below formula.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,A:A,">="&A2,A:A,"<"&A2+1/24)/15
```

Might have mixed up between 1 hour and 3 hours in my question, but all you have to do is change the values in ...**1**/24)/**15**

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I notice now that you want average. My answer gives you the sum. But just replace SUM with AVERAGE.

If that is true dates then you can use this formula. If not make the cells in column A real dates.

This finds the first cell that is less than three hours old and concatenates it to a range.

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(TRUE,A:A>A5-(1/24*3),0)&":B"&ROW()))
```

You need to change the A5 to A16 (or 15?) and place this formula in the column C of row 15 (or 16...). The first row where you have three hour span.

See my simple example here:
Note that 14:00 is missing and thus I get three rows with value "3"

[image]